# Duplicate Rows in Google Spreadsheet based on Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to programatically duplicate rows in a Google spreadsheet. I would like the number of times the row is duplicated to be based on one of the values in the row itself.

For example, lets say I have a table like this:

[image]

You can see that there are numbers in column C. The value in column C is the number of times I would like to duplicate the row. This is what the desired result would look like:

[image]

Technically, if the value in column C was 3, we would be duplicating the row two times.

Any ideas on how to script a Google spreadsheet to do this would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is fairly simple and you should have tried it yourself. I'm sure that when you'll read the code below you'll say "Oh, of course, I could have done it easily"... right ?

```
function autoDup() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for(var n in data){
    newData.push(data[n]);
    if(!Number(data[n][2])){continue};// if column 3 is not a number then do nothing
    for(var c=1 ; c < Number(data[n][2]) ; c++){ // start from 1 instead of 0 because we have already 1 copy
      newData.push(data[n]);//store values
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);// write new data to sheet, overwriting old data
}
```

Comment: Serge,  awesome response, as always!

Comment: Very clean and succinct!  I would expect nothing less from you!  The only thing I would suggest to add would be to sort the new data range.... e.g. var newData = sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);  newData.sort({column: 1, ascending: false}); // to be inline with the descending sort of column 1 in the example.

Comment: @Cyrus Loree-thanks for the kind words.  I think the script does not change the data order...what makes you think it does?

Comment: btw, since the sort method you use is a `range` method you could have chained it like this :  `sheet.getRange(1,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData).sort({column: 1, ascending: false});`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is on inSheet, on a different sheet you can place the following formula `=transpose(split(arrayformula(textjoin(",",false,iferror(rept(inSheet!A1:A&",",inSheet!$C1:$C)))),","))` and drag it right twice and you're done.
This could be bulletproofed to handle empty cells or ones with commas or repeat values of 0, but for nice data like above, it works as is.